# Word for a quote that was never actually said

Tags: single-word-requests

Many well-known quotes such as "Elementary, my dear Watson" were never actually said by the person they are attributed to.

Is there a specific word that means this kind of quote? If not, is there a more general word for commonly held belief that is wrong?

Comment: Strictly, of course, Sherlock Holmes of 221B Baker Street never said anything at all. A misquote is when the words are mangled (as in the above fictional case). A false attribution is when the person allegedly being quoted is the wrong one. And a common misconception is a two-word phrase used to describe the last case above.

Comment: Forgive me for being a stickler, but shouldn't your word "quotes" be "quotations"?  Quote is a verb; a quotation is a noun.  For example:  I like to quote Alexander the Great, who in that famous quotation said, "I came, I saw, I conquered."  [I'm not sure he actually said those words; they are illustrative only.]

Comment: @rhetorician ...That was said by Caesar, not Alexander.

Comment: @rhetorician "Quote is a verb; a quotation is a noun." should have been *was* & *was*; no longer *is* & *is*. http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/quote?q=quote

Comment: @EdwinAshworth A fictional character named Sherlock Holmes certainly has said "Elementary, my dear Watson" (in the sense that fictional characters can say anything). It's Conan Doyle to whom it's misattributed, since _his_ Holmes never said it.

Comment: @Sȱɳɨȼ Ʈħe ǶḝÐɠḝħȱɠ I thought he spoke Latin.

Comment: @gmcgath Not to nitpick, but in the sense that fictional characters can say anything, then we can attribute any certain words to a character claiming that they have said those words as quotes; In all 60 Sherlock Holmes books by Conan, Holmes never actually says "Elementary, my dear Watson", unfortunately.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth [Veni, vidi, vici](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veni,_vidi,_vici)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The word *[apocryphal](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/apocryphal#Adjective)* is commonly used for made-up writings; its senses include  “Of doubtful authenticity, or lacking authority; not regarded as canonical” and  “Of dubious veracity; of questionable accuracy or truthfulness; anecdotal or in the nature of an urban legend”.

Comment: Thanks, I spent the last 20 minuets failing to google for that word. I was starting to wonder if I had imagined it in the first place. 

I'll accept the answer when it lets me.

Comment: 'Apocryphal' means 'dubious' not 'definitely wrong'.

Answer (score 3):

Is there a word for this kind of quote? Sure there is: ***misquote*** (or *misquotation*).

NOAD lists *misquote* as both a verb and a noun, with the noun defined as *a passage or remark quoted inaccurately*. Most dictionaries I checked, though (such as [this one](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/misquote)), listed *misquote* as a verb, and *misquotation* as the noun:

> **misquotation**: an instance of quoting something incorrectly, or of something being quoted incorrectly (from [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/misquotation))

Comment: "Misquote" implies that the person said something like it, but it's been distorted. It doesn't apply when the quotation is completely made up.

Comment: @gmcgath: I wondered about that same thing, and that's how I often see the term used. As for Holmes' "Elementary, my dear Watson," it seems a gray area as to whether or not the word _misquoted_ would apply. The literary Holmes never uttered that, but Basil Rathbone's cinematic version did, to the point where it became trite. Getting back to the O.P.'s question, though, namely: _Is there a word for a quotation never actually said by the person it is attributed to?_ I don't think _misquote_ is too far off the mark there.

Answer (score 2):

***Spurious*** can be used for this purpose for wrongly attributed "facts".